# Exception while parsing Date

Tags: android

I'm getting a datetime from a webservice, wich is actually pulling the data from a sqlserver db, the problem is I'm getting a parse exception when I try to convert the string to Date:

Here is my code:

```
String tschedule = json.getString("ScheduledFor");
String tduration = json.getString("Duration");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

Date schedule = new Date();
Date duration = new Date();

try
{
schedule = dateFormat.parse(tschedule); //exception here, tschedule="2013-04-12T11:25:26.703"  
duration = dateFormat1.parse(tduration);//or exception here, tduration="03:10:00"
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
Log.e("MEETINGS SERVICE", "Parse exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Logcat ouptut:
04-18 18:54:48.690: E/MEETINGS SERVICE(8601): DateParse exception: Unparseable date: 2013-04-12T11:25:26.703

Comment: Please, comment why the downvoting

Comment: What is the exception? Are you sure the strings are correct? The values in the comments work fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the fractional seconds (the bold part):

> DateParse exception: Unparseable date: 2013-04-12T11:25:26**.703**

Make sure you change your pattern to include those:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```